# Copy a PostgreSQL (ver. 9.6) database without any user interruption?

Tags: postgresql, clone

Is it possible to clone a prod PostgreSQL 9 database for testing purposes without interrupting the user experience (means disconnecting any user)? If yes, what would be the command to use?

Comment: Sure, you can use pg_dump or pg_basebackup to make a complete backup. Version 9.6 is EOL, you'd better upgrade to version 14 to get a supported version. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/reference-client.html

Comment: Yeah thanks, that's then plan. This question is in course of the migration.